# Fading a DIV In and Out Based on Nav Bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Greetings,

I am trying to make a simple fade in / fade out DIV with text for each button on a navigation bar using jQuery and I'm running into some problems. Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[image: Screenshot]

Basically, when the user hovers over an item on the nav bar, a div appears below the navigation with text related to that button. The markup I have come up with so far is horrendous and I know it is not the correct way to go about this, I also attempted using an array and filling the info div with text from the nav button's title attribute - the latter worked great but then a title also appears.

Apart from being too complex, it does work.. to a point. If the user hovers in and out of the nav bar rapidly it causes the whole thing to flash on and off (without using :hidden and :visible) or does not appear if :hidden and :visible are used.

Here is the current markup:

**CSS for the info DIV**

```
#header-info-text {
    width: 480px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-right:  25px;
    background: url('/images/info-arrow.png') top right no-repeat transparent scroll;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML for nav**

```
<div id="navBar">
      <ul>
          <li class="nav-first nav-active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li id="navAbout"><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li id="navPort"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li id="navServ"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li id="navBlog"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li id="navContact" class="nav-last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div id="header-infoDIV">
      <span id="header-info-text"></span>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#navBar ul li").hover(function() {
     var text;
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     if (id == 'navAbout') {
     text = 'Learn more ..';
     } else if (id == 'navPort') {
      text = 'View our recent work and ongoing projects';
      } else if (id == 'navServ') {
      text = 'Learn about our services';
      } else if (id == 'navBlog') {
      text = 'View the our Blog';
      } else if (id == 'navContact') {
      text = 'We\'re looking forward to working with you!';
      } else {
      text = '';
       }
      $("#header-info-text").text(text);
      $("#header-info-text:hidden").fadeIn('slow');
      });
            $("#navBar ul").hover(function() {
                $("#header-info-text:hidden").fadeIn('slow');
            }, function() {
                $("#header-info-text:visible").delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
            });
```

What is the best way to tackle this sort of thing? Basically, I want to fade in the info text's DIV, change its text when the user moves to another button, and hide it when they move out of the nav bar.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION (thanks to jmans)**

```
 $("#navBar ul").hover(function() {
        $("#header-info-text").stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $("#header-info-text").stop(true,true).delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to mVChr's suggestion, the code has been reduced to a few lines. Combined with the suggestion provided by jmans, it's doing what I wanted it to:

```
$("#navBar ul li a").hover(function() {
                var text = $(this).attr('rel');
                $("#header-info-text").text(text);
                $("#header-info-text").stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
            },
            function() { 
               $("#header-info-text").stop(true,true).delay(500).fadeOut('slow');
            });
```

Comment: +1 for following up your question.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the stop() method to halt any ongoing animations when the hover state changes:

```
        $("#navBar ul").hover(function() {
            $("#header-info-text:hidden").stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
            $("#header-info-text:visible").stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow');
        });
```

As well as on the other animation call.

Comment: Works like a charm! Added a delay for fadeOut, apparently that got left out of my original code. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the flickering you're talking about, is it happening in a specific browser?  I tested on Chrome and Firefox.

However, I did make [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EanzV/2/) in order to show you how you can improve your code by separating content from functionality.  Basically, if you wanted to update the status text, the sensible place to look would be in the HTML, not the code.  Also, having all of those specific conditionals in the code is not very maintainable.  Think if you wanted to add or change a few menu items.

Instead, I moved the status text to the `title` attribute of the links in your HTML and had the jQuery read that attribute to get the text.  This also reduces the first 15 lines of your jQuery code to 6 lines:

```
$("#navBar ul li a").hover(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr('title');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#header-info-text").text(text);
    $("#header-info-text:hidden").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Ironically, that's the EXACT code I came up with after banging my head against the wall with the code posted in my question. The only problem I ran into with that solution is that the title was appearing over the nav button, very obtrusive and redundant. But, from a scripting standpoint, this would have been the best solution. And it wasn't so much of a flicker - basically, it was repeating the fadeIn and fadeOut for every time that .hover() was called

Comment: If you want to avoid the title hovering over the menu then you can use the `rel` attribute instead just changing line 2 to use `attr('rel')`.  If you ever have problems again with unwanted animations repeating, look into the `.stop()` method in the jQuery API docs.

Comment: Of course! Brilliant! Thanks for your help, combined with the other answer and it's working just how I wanted it to.